# Copy table from one database to another in multiple threads in C++

Tags: c++, sql, postgresql, multithreading, performance

There is a huge SQL table in Postgres Database. I'd like to copy the contents of it to another different database (SQL Server) using `C++`. I have written a single-thread application and it works fine.

I decided to use multiple threads to increase the performance of reading and writing data. Here in the code below I execute the `SELECT` query in order to get the data from one DB and write it into `KeyValue` data structure, which holds the data intermediately. Then I form an `INSERT` query for another DB and execute it.

I have parallelized writing into `KeyValue` by dividing the data into multiple blocks.

```
void copy_table(dbName, ...) {
    // PostgreSQL
    Postgres* pg = new Postgres();
    int res = pg->Connect(dbName);
    
    // define number of blocks the table is to be divided in
    std::size_t blockNum = get_block_num(pg, dbName, copyTableName);

    // select all the data from table
    PGresult* pgres = nullptr;
    std::string pqQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + copyTableName;
    res = pg->Execute(pqQuery, &pgres);

    // write the attribute names into a KeyValue store
    int nFields = PQnfields(pgres);

    std::vector<std::string> keys;
    for (int i = 0; i < nFields; i++)
    {
        keys.push_back(std::string(PQfname(pgres, i)));
    }

    int nRows = PQntuples(pgres);

    // Create a KeyValue store of size nFields * nRows with keys
    KeyValue* keyValue = new KeyValue(nFields, nRows, keys);

    // check hardware concurrency
    int threadNum = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    if (threadNum < blockNum)
        blockNum = threadNum;

    // parse the data and write it into KeyValue store
    std::vector<std::thread> v_thread(blockNum);
    for (int i = 0; i < blockNum; ++i)
    {
        v_thread[i] = std::thread(get_value, i, i, nRows, nFields, blockNum, keyValue, pgres);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < blockNum; ++i)
    {
        v_thread[i].join();
    }
    delete pg;

    // SQL Server
    OleDB* oleDBp = new OleDB(serverName, dataSource, userName, password);
    std::string query{};
    create_query(query, keyValue, values, replicaTableName, blockNum);
    int result = oleDBp->Connect();

    result = oleDBp->Execute(query);
    delete oleDBp;
    delete keyValue;
}
```

In `get_data` each thread fills the `KeyValue` with data in different blocks.

```
// get value by row
// thread routine function
void get_value(int tid, int block_counter, int nRows, int nFields, std::size_t block_num,
    KeyValue* keyValue, PGresult* pgres)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nFields; i++) {
        // read rows corresponding to certain block
        for (int j = block_counter * (nRows / block_num); j < (std::size_t(block_counter) + 1) * (nRows / block_num); j++) {
            char* value = PQgetvalue(pgres, j, i);
            keyValue->insert(value, i + j * nFields);
        }
    }
}
```

1. Is it possible to increase the performance of `SELECT` query using multiple threads? The point is that it requires more queries to be executed and it might increase the latency.
2. The same question regarding `INSERT`. In addition, is there any safety issues followed by insert operation?
3. Could you give some suggestions how to improve the performance? The approach I used in `get_data` does not seem to be extremely helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The programming language Lua was originally designed to be used to be a database-neutral language to move data from one database to another different database.  (It has since been used for many other things, since it is a general purpose embedded scripting language.)

Comment: @Eljay Thank you for the information! Unfortunately, the whole project is written in C++ and requires `copy_table` function to be written also in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Start several threads or processes that each connect to both databases.
- Start a `REPEATABLE READ READ ONLY` transaction to the source database in each thread.
- Use the [snapshot synchronization functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-SNAPSHOT-SYNCHRONIZATION) so that all sessions see the same snapshot of the source database and get consistent data.
- Have each session perform a query like

  ```
  SELECT * FROM atable WHERE id % n = k;
  ```

  where `n` is the number of threads and `k` is the thread number.
- If you start all queries at about the same time, you will get [synchonized sequential scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC_SYNCHRONIZE_SEQSCANS), which will cause each block to be read from storage only once.
- Make sure that you insert rows into the target databases in transactions spanning some 1000 rows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It helps me a lot. Can you please clarify if it is better to read rows block by block, e.g. `0 to k` for 0 thread, `k + 1 to 2k ` for 1st thread and so on. In comparison to your variant `id % n = k`, the variant above reads data sequentially.

Comment: My suggestion should result in sequential scans. Are you talking about table blocks? If you mean "blocks of primary key values", then you'd probably get an index scan, which should be slower.

Comment: I have read about sequential scans and index scans in PostgreSQL after your reply. Sequential scans are preferable for my case. Thank you again!